# Reading function from a file in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have an optimization solver in Fortran 90. So, if I want to change the objective function 
I have to modified the main file and write the objective function in this way:

```
  subroutine fobj(n,x,f)
    implicit none
    integer :: n
    real(8) :: f
    real(8) :: x(n)
    intent(in ) :: n,x
    intent(out) :: f
    !OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
    f = x(1)**2-x(2)+2*x(3)
   end subroutine fobj
```

I have a big objective function, so I want to call this line "f = x(1)**2-x(2)+2*x(3)" from an external file or at least the subrutine.

Is that possible? (I'm new in Fortran.)

I know that I can modified the file with Python, but I want to do it in other file.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not quite sure, what you want to call from where?

Comment: Not quite sure also: do you want to modifie the function before or after compilation? In Fortran, you can't modifie a source file after the compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Use:

```
include 'file.inc'
```

to include source code from an external file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but:

Fortran also allows you to pass subroutine/function names around as actual arguments to subroutine/function calls.  The corresponding dummy arguments must have the "external" attribute.

```
subroutine fobj(n,x,f,func)
  implicit none
  integer :: n
  real(8),external :: func
  real(8) :: f
  real(8) :: x(n)
  intent(in ) :: n,x
  intent(out) :: f
  !OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
  f=func(x,n)
end subroutine fobj

function func1(x,n)
  implicit none
  real(8) func1
  integer n
  real(8) :: f,x(n)
  f = x(1)**2-x(2)+2*x(3)
end function  func1

function func2(x,n)
  implicit none
  real(8) func2
  integer n
  real(8) :: f,x(n)
  f = x(1)**2+x(2)+2*x(3)
end function func2

program main
  real(8),external :: func1,func2
  real(8),allocatable :: x(:)
  real(8) :: f
  integer n
  n=50

  allocate(x(n))  
  x=10.  !Set X to a known value
  call fobj(n,x,f,func1) !Call func1
  print*,f  !10**2-10+2*10 = 110
  x=10.  !Reset X ... just to make sure there is no funny business in func1,func2
  call fobj(n,x,f,func2) !Call func2
  print*,f  !10**2+10+2*10 = 130
  deallocate(x)

end program main
```

Of course, this program does nothing useful other than call func1 and func2 in obscure ways, but hopefully it illustrates the point.  If you're looking to switch out the function at compile-time, then I think a `include "myfile"` is probably cleaner (just switching which file you're including at the time as suggested by @AlejandroLL)

Answer (score 2):

You might also try to use Modules in your program. Sometimes when you pass special variables to your subroutines/functions you need to write interfaces for them. Using modules will improve your program structure and you'll be more effective and all interfaces would be generated automatically.